Electrical Assistance Control Unit Malfunctioning After Accident
Recently, I was involved in an accident while riding an o2feel electric bike. Since then, I've been experiencing some issues with the bike's electrical system. When I pedal forward, the bike emits strange noises, and the electrical assistance control unit (reference: Shimano Steps E6010, link: https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/city---trekking-e-bike-e6100-series/SW-E6010-L.html) appears to be malfunctioning. Despite my efforts, I have been unable to find any documentation specifically related to this component. I have also tried to open the control unit to inspect the electronics, but I haven't been able to access the inside of it without needing to break it. I would greatly appreciate any assistance you can provide in identifying the root cause of this issue and finding relevant resources to help me troubleshoot and potentially repair the Shimano Steps E6010 electrical assistance control unit.
Thank you in advance for your time and consideration.

Was there another party who caused this accident?  If so, its their job to make it right.
